# SSH Hangs after being logged in for ~30 seconds

Tags: networking, ssh

This is likely an issue with my network however I thought someone here might have some steps to help troubleshoot. I currently can log into the server just fine via SSH but about 30 seconds to 40 seconds later it completely hangs.

From the packet capture I can see that packets are being sent back and forth between the client and server ssh process until the end where it's just my server repeatedly trying to send it packets without getting anything back.

Here is a good part of the tcpdump

```
18:49:28.466635 IP 10.0.2.11.58776 > 10.0.3.5.22: Flags [.], ack 2490, win 274, options [nop,nop,TS val 1248808280 ecr 19660300], length 0
18:49:28.466990 IP 10.0.2.11.58776 > 10.0.3.5.22: Flags [P.], seq 1904:2356, ack 2490, win 274, options [nop,nop,TS val 1248808281 ecr 19660300], length 452
18:49:28.468229 IP 10.0.3.5.22 > 10.0.2.11.58776: Flags [.], ack 2356, win 294, options [nop,nop,TS val 19660301 ecr 1248808281], length 0
18:49:28.470848 IP 10.0.3.5.22 > 10.0.2.11.58776: Flags [P.], seq 2490:2598, ack 2356, win 294, options [nop,nop,TS val 19660301 ecr 1248808281], length 108
18:49:28.471451 IP 10.0.3.5.22 > 10.0.2.11.58776: Flags [P.], seq 2598:2850, ack 2356, win 294, options [nop,nop,TS val 19660301 ecr 1248808281], length 252
18:49:28.471489 IP 10.0.3.5.22 > 10.0.2.11.58776: Flags [P.], seq 2850:3006, ack 2356, win 294, options [nop,nop,TS val 19660301 ecr 1248808281], length 156
18:49:28.471591 IP 10.0.2.11.58776 > 10.0.3.5.22: Flags [.], ack 3006, win 305, options [nop,nop,TS val 1248808285 ecr 19660301], length 0
18:49:28.615964 IP 10.0.3.5.22 > 10.0.2.11.58776: Flags [P.], seq 3006:3106, ack 2356, win 294, options [nop,nop,TS val 19660337 ecr 1248808285], length 100
18:49:28.656916 IP 10.0.2.11.58776 > 10.0.3.5.22: Flags [.], ack 3106, win 305, options [nop,nop,TS val 1248808471 ecr 19660337], length 0
18:49:33.621448 IP 10.0.2.11.58776 > 10.0.3.5.22: Flags [P.], seq 2356:2408, ack 3106, win 305, options [nop,nop,TS val 1248813435 ecr 19660337], length 52
18:49:33.623447 IP 10.0.3.5.22 > 10.0.2.11.58776: Flags [P.], seq 3106:3134, ack 2408, win 294, options [nop,nop,TS val 19661589 ecr 1248813435], length 28
18:49:33.623509 IP 10.0.2.11.58776 > 10.0.3.5.22: Flags [.], ack 3134, win 305, options [nop,nop,TS val 1248813437 ecr 19661589], length 0
18:49:38.628948 IP 10.0.2.11.58776 > 10.0.3.5.22: Flags [P.], seq 2408:2460, ack 3134, win 305, options [nop,nop,TS val 1248818443 ecr 19661589], length 52
18:49:38.630927 IP 10.0.3.5.22 > 10.0.2.11.58776: Flags [P.], seq 3134:3162, ack 2460, win 294, options [nop,nop,TS val 19662841 ecr 1248818443], length 28
18:49:38.630981 IP 10.0.2.11.58776 > 10.0.3.5.22: Flags [.], ack 3162, win 305, options [nop,nop,TS val 1248818445 ecr 19662841], length 0
18:49:43.636271 IP 10.0.2.11.58776 > 10.0.3.5.22: Flags [P.], seq 2460:2512, ack 3162, win 305, options [nop,nop,TS val 1248823450 ecr 19662841], length 52
18:49:43.637913 IP 10.0.3.5.22 > 10.0.2.11.58776: Flags [P.], seq 3162:3190, ack 2512, win 294, options [nop,nop,TS val 19664093 ecr 1248823450], length 28
18:49:43.637970 IP 10.0.2.11.58776 > 10.0.3.5.22: Flags [.], ack 3190, win 305, options [nop,nop,TS val 1248823452 ecr 19664093], length 0
18:49:48.641414 IP 10.0.2.11.58776 > 10.0.3.5.22: Flags [P.], seq 2512:2564, ack 3190, win 305, options [nop,nop,TS val 1248828455 ecr 19664093], length 52
18:49:48.643492 IP 10.0.3.5.22 > 10.0.2.11.58776: Flags [P.], seq 3190:3218, ack 2564, win 294, options [nop,nop,TS val 19665344 ecr 1248828455], length 28
18:49:48.643575 IP 10.0.2.11.58776 > 10.0.3.5.22: Flags [.], ack 3218, win 305, options [nop,nop,TS val 1248828457 ecr 19665344], length 0
18:49:53.649083 IP 10.0.2.11.58776 > 10.0.3.5.22: Flags [P.], seq 2564:2616, ack 3218, win 305, options [nop,nop,TS val 1248833463 ecr 19665344], length 52
18:49:53.650953 IP 10.0.3.5.22 > 10.0.2.11.58776: Flags [P.], seq 3218:3246, ack 2616, win 294, options [nop,nop,TS val 19666596 ecr 1248833463], length 28
18:49:53.651018 IP 10.0.2.11.58776 > 10.0.3.5.22: Flags [.], ack 3246, win 305, options [nop,nop,TS val 1248833465 ecr 19666596], length 0
18:49:58.656273 IP 10.0.2.11.58776 > 10.0.3.5.22: Flags [P.], seq 2616:2668, ack 3246, win 305, options [nop,nop,TS val 1248838470 ecr 19666596], length 52
18:49:58.658237 IP 10.0.3.5.22 > 10.0.2.11.58776: Flags [P.], seq 3246:3274, ack 2668, win 294, options [nop,nop,TS val 19667848 ecr 1248838470], length 28
18:49:58.658292 IP 10.0.2.11.58776 > 10.0.3.5.22: Flags [.], ack 3274, win 305, options [nop,nop,TS val 1248838472 ecr 19667848], length 0
18:50:03.663677 IP 10.0.2.11.58776 > 10.0.3.5.22: Flags [P.], seq 2668:2720, ack 3274, win 305, options [nop,nop,TS val 1248843477 ecr 19667848], length 52
18:50:03.665593 IP 10.0.3.5.22 > 10.0.2.11.58776: Flags [P.], seq 3274:3302, ack 2720, win 294, options [nop,nop,TS val 19669100 ecr 1248843477], length 28
18:50:03.665656 IP 10.0.2.11.58776 > 10.0.3.5.22: Flags [.], ack 3302, win 305, options [nop,nop,TS val 1248843479 ecr 19669100], length 0
18:50:08.671149 IP 10.0.2.11.58776 > 10.0.3.5.22: Flags [P.], seq 2720:2772, ack 3302, win 305, options [nop,nop,TS val 1248848485 ecr 19669100], length 52
18:50:08.879977 IP 10.0.2.11.58776 > 10.0.3.5.22: Flags [P.], seq 2720:2772, ack 3302, win 305, options [nop,nop,TS val 1248848694 ecr 19669100], length 52
18:50:09.087980 IP 10.0.2.11.58776 > 10.0.3.5.22: Flags [P.], seq 2720:2772, ack 3302, win 305, options [nop,nop,TS val 1248848902 ecr 19669100], length 52
18:50:09.503964 IP 10.0.2.11.58776 > 10.0.3.5.22: Flags [P.], seq 2720:2772, ack 3302, win 305, options [nop,nop,TS val 1248849318 ecr 19669100], length 52
18:50:10.360063 IP 10.0.2.11.58776 > 10.0.3.5.22: Flags [P.], seq 2720:2772, ack 3302, win 305, options [nop,nop,TS val 1248850174 ecr 19669100], length 52
18:50:12.023959 IP 10.0.2.11.58776 > 10.0.3.5.22: Flags [P.], seq 2720:2772, ack 3302, win 305, options [nop,nop,TS val 1248851838 ecr 19669100], length 52
18:50:15.352072 IP 10.0.2.11.58776 > 10.0.3.5.22: Flags [P.], seq 2720:2772, ack 3302, win 305, options [nop,nop,TS val 1248855166 ecr 19669100], length 52
```

on the server side of SSH it looks almost identical except due to NAT rules the server sees 10.0.0.10 instead of 10.0.2.11 however the port is the same.

If I log directly into the server I am trying to SSH to I can continually ping it without issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated. It seems odd that packets are flowing and then seemingly all of a sudden just stop.

This doesn't seem to be an MTU issue as everything in my network is set to 1500 and I can ping both systems from each other using `ping 10.0.3.5 -s 1472 -D`.

Comment: Huh if it isn't pmtu then maybe the connection tracking used by the NAT device isn't working properly or table that stores NAT info is overflowing. What is the NAT device?

Comment: The NAT device is a Linksys WRT AC3200. It is only happening from that device if i how on the router that it connects to I can ssh onto the server that is hanging without issues.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a path mtu issue. It is common enough to have a [FAQ entry in the snail book](http://www.snailbook.com/faq/mtu-mismatch.auto.html).

Comment: Ah! I didn't even think about this because I was assuming everything on the network had the MTU set to 1500 however this is likely the case... Going to confirm now that all routers have the proper MTU set.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case... I just checked every interface between my client and the server and all are set to use MTU of 1500.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Check if there is another way the packages can flow from your client to server and vice versa, also known as [asymmetric routing](https://www.auvik.com/franklyit/blog/asymmetric-routing-issue/)

I had the same issue, but resolved it differently.
MTU was correctly set up on all devices, but the ssh connection would still freeze after approx 30s.
After some googling I found [this post](https://forum.opnsense.org/index.php?topic=27848.0):

> The remote host was connected to the LAN through the wireless adapter, so all traffic from the remote host was delivered locally,

Which hinted me at the correct solution. My server was in a different LAN separated by a firewall, however, due to testing I had setup a second NIC on the same network as the client. This resulted in the problem, where the client would send packages to the server via the firewall, but the server would respond through the NIC that was directly attached to the client network, instead of using the firewall.

As diagram:

```
client --ssh--> firewall --ssh--> NIC_1 server
  ^                                  |
  |                                  V
  +-----------------ssh---------- NIC_2 server
```

Since the answer is not routed through the firewall it assumes that the connection failed and closes it after 30s.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty specific to my setup however if other people run into this issue and it's not MTU being set incorrectly (It likely is that issue for most who see this) check your firewall settings.

I disabled the firewall for all ports in my LAN and this issue resolved itself. I'm going to do some more playing to find what exactly was being blocked where when I have some more time.